# Django model field through linked relationship

Tags: python, django, model

Is there a way to create a "virtual" field in a model linked to a field in a relationship?

e.g. I have:

```
class User(models.Model):
   organization = models.ForeignKey(
        "Organization", ...
    )
```

Organization model have a field `name`

so I want to add a virtual field in `User` model (e.g `organization_name`) to be able to do `user.organization_name` instead of `user.organization.name`

is it possible?

Comment: Add a method which is a property to your class? (Decorate the method by `@property`)

Comment: Thanks @AbdulAzizBarkat ! This is what I'm doing now. Was wondering if there is another why to do that.. but that's working fine this way too

Comment: I wouldn't do that - it would just cause confusion later on when you're in the ORM and doing `select_related`or `prefetch_related`. Just use the dot notation - what's the problem with that?

Answer (score 1):

You can [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate) the value. For example:

```
from django.db.models import F

for u in User.objects.annotate(name=F('organization__name')):
    print(u.name)
```

Comment: This is a better approach as it aligns with use of the ORM,